# Adjust layout of accordion section header - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, accordion

I am using an accordion LWC populating it with a list. My lightning-accordion-section tag looks like this

```
<lightning-accordion-section key={account.accountId} name={account.accountId} label={account.accountHeader}>
...[Bunch of Stuff]
</lightning-accordion-section>
```

My problem is my account.accountHeader field has several pieces of information, but they are of different lengths, making my accordion look a jumble. Is there any way to lay out the accordion section header similar to a datatable with spaced and aligned columns down the accordion-sections?

The complexity of my ...[Bunch of Stuff] stops me using a tree grid. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem you are facing?

Comment: it's a bit hard as it has confidential information on it